# Get the column name that has different value Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have 2 dataframes with same column names, I want to get the column name that has different value.

df1(old file)

```
   SYMBOL  PPUP  R_5UP  R1UP  R2UP R2_5UP  R3UP  R3_5UP  R4UP
  NMRUSDT  True   True  True  True   True   NaN     NaN   NaN
SPELLUSDT  True   True   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
 YFIIUSDT  True   True  True   NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
```

df2 (new file)

```
   SYMBOL  PPUP R_5UP  R1UP  R2UP R2_5UP  R3UP  R3_5UP  R4UP
  NMRUSDT  True  True  True  True   True   NaN     NaN   NaN
SPELLUSDT  True   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
 YFIIUSDT  True  True  True  True    NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN
```

DF expected result:

```
   SYMBOL oldfilelasttruecolumn newfilelasttruecolumn  stepgain
SPELLUSDT                 R_5UP                  PPUP        -1
 YFIIUSDT                  R1UP                  R2UP        +1
```

I only managed to remove all the rows that has the exacts same values using

```
duplicates = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).to_string(index=False, header=False)
```

but now I'm stucked.
This seems a little bit hard to do.

Comment: Can you have more True after the first NaN?

Comment: @mozway can't have any True after a Nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
idx1 = df1.set_index('SYMBOL').stack().groupby(level='SYMBOL').sum()
idx2 = df2.set_index('SYMBOL').stack().groupby(level='SYMBOL').sum()

out = (pd.DataFrame({'old': df1.columns.to_numpy()[list(idx1)],
                     'new': df2.columns.to_numpy()[list(idx2)],
                     'stepgain': idx2-idx1
                    })
         .reset_index().loc[lambda d: d['stepgain'].ne(0)]
      )
```

output:

```
      SYMBOL    old   new stepgain
1  SPELLUSDT  R_5UP  PPUP       -1
2   YFIIUSDT   R1UP  R2UP        1
```

Comment: If you can reformat the dataframes from question ;-)

Comment: @mozway sometime it works, but sometime i got an error:     raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: @Oneboy this could mean that you have cases where the 2 dataframes don't have the same number of rows, is it the case?

Comment: @mozway I have checked and my 2 dataframes have the same number of rows. It seems to get an error when old file DF has only "NaN" values and new file DF has 1 or more "True".  In that case idx1 has less row

Comment: I see, good point, then you can probably `reindex`: `idx1 = df1.set_index('SYMBOL').stack().groupby(level='SYMBOL').sum().reindex(df1['SYMBOL'])`, same for `idx2`